# Error loading SDSFoundations package in R 4.0.3 for MAC

Tags: r

I installed R on my mac (Version 4.0.3) and after this, I downloaded the SDSFoundations package to the desktop (.tar file).
I installed the package with the following command:
`install.packages("~/Desktop/SDSFoundations_1.1_R_x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0.tar", repos = NULL, type = 'source')`
[I added the 'type = 'source' because I was getting an error that repos = NULL could not be used with type = 'binary']
The package installed successfully.

PROBLEM: when I tried to load the package with
`library(SDSFoundations)`
I am getting the error: `package or namespace load failed for ‘SDSFoundations’: package ‘SDSFoundations’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it`

`.libPaths()` points to `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library`
`find.package("SDSFoundations")` gives me `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/SDSFoundations`

I do not understand what I am doing wrong. R 4.0.3 is the first R version I have ever installed on this system and right after this, I installed the SDSFoundations package. I do not understand why I am not able to load the package. Please help!

Comment: This is an issue with the package maintainer to solve. You'll have to contact them.

Answer (score 0):

So the past few days, I had the same problem and when I hit the

installed_packages()

SDSFoundations --------            "3.2.3"

it showed me that SDSFoundations never upgraded from ****R 3.2.3.****

The best thing to do is install the R version before 4.0.0 side to side with your newer versions and you can shift to the versions in the Rstudio. To be precise open the window from the TOOL/Global Options..., and from that window, you can choose your desired versions from the tool RGeneral/R version.
At last, it will ask you to restart the Rstudio every time you change it but in the end, it worked perfectly for me.
Hope this will help anyone who needs this info. ;)